# Laravel Middleware changing header before passing to controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, jwt, laravel-middleware

I'm trying to change the header of my request before passing it to the controller using a middleware but it seems `$next($request)` executes the code in my controller. Is there a way to change the header then send the updated request to my controller?

My middleware:

```
class JWTAuthenticator
{

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{   
    $token =JWTAuth::getToken();
    $my_new_token = JWTAuth::refresh($token);
    //it runs here
    $response = $next($request);

    //it runs this part after executing the controller  
    $response->header('Authorization','Bearer '.$my_new_token);
    return $response;
}
```

This is how the middleware is assigned to my route:

```
Route::get('/{user}', 'v1\UserController@find')->middleware('jwt_auth');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That way you are excecuting the `$response->header('Authorization','Bearer '.$my_new_token);` sentence after the request was attended.
Change your code as follows:

```
class JWTAuthenticator
{

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{   
    $token =JWTAuth::getToken();
    $my_new_token = JWTAuth::refresh($token);

    $request->headers->set('Authorization','Bearer '.$my_new_token);

    return $next($request);
}
```